# Spring MVC + JSON/REST GET method connection Working code reference

Tags: json, spring, jsp, rest, spring-mvc

I was in the process of writing a logic to print retrieved JSON data in a web page, for which I have a controller class, domain class and hello.jsp file.

This is the JSON data which I am getting and which I am trying to display in the webpage

```
[{"uname":"sam","fileSize":"26 MB","fileName":"Subway_Surfers","downloadSize":1381186649389},
{"uname":"sam","fileSize":"8 MB","fileName":"Grand_Theft_Auto","downloadSize":1381186668752},
```

But this *hello.jsp* was not getting invoked and i posted in this forum. Didn't get any proper response. After which one of my friend helped in resolving this since the script url was incorrect.

After modifying the script url in *hello.jsp* file to `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">` it worked fine.

So I am attaching the working code for controller class, domain class and *hello.jsp* for reference in setting up a simple Spring MVC + JSON/REST GET method connection.

**Domain Class**

```
    public class OperatorBilling implements Serializable {

    private String uname;

    private String fileSize;

    private String fileName;

    private Timestamp downloadSize;

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getFileSize() {
        return fileSize;
    }

    public void setFileSize(String fileSize) {
        this.fileSize = fileSize;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }

    public Timestamp getDownloadSize() {
        return downloadSize;
    }

    public void setDownloadSize(Timestamp downloadSize) {
        this.downloadSize = downloadSize;
    }
   }
```

**Controller class**

```
package com.springapp.mvc;

import com.springapp.domain.OperatorBilling;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/",method = RequestMethod.GET)

    public String getOperatorBillingDetails(ModelMap model) {
       OperatorBilling operatorBilling  = new OperatorBilling();
       model.addAttribute("operatorBilling",operatorBilling)  ;
       return "hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/hello",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json;charset=utf-8")

    public @ResponseBody
    Object getOperatorBillingDetails() {
        List<OperatorBilling> operatorBillingList = new ArrayList<OperatorBilling>();
        try {

            URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/operatorBilling");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                        + conn.getResponseCode());
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    (conn.getInputStream())));

            String output;

            System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
            while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] str = output.split("},");
                for(int i =0;i<str.length;i++){
                    String[] str1 = str[i].split(",");

                    OperatorBilling operatorBilling = new OperatorBilling();
                    for(int j =0;j<str1.length;j++){


                        str1[j]= str1[j].replaceAll("\\[\\{","")  ;
                        str1[j]= str1[j].replaceAll("\\}\\]","")  ;
                        str1[j]= str1[j].replaceAll("\"","")  ;
                        str1[j]= str1[j].replaceAll("\\{","")  ;
                        str1[j]= str1[j].replaceAll("\\}","")  ;


                        if(str1[j].contains("uname:")){
                            str1[j] = str1[j].substring(6,str1[j].length());
                            operatorBilling.setUname(str1[j]);

                        }

                        if(str1[j].contains("fileName:")){
                            str1[j] = str1[j].substring(9,str1[j].length());
                            operatorBilling.setFileName(str1[j]);

                        }

                        if(str1[j].contains("fileSize:")){
                            str1[j] = str1[j].substring(9,str1[j].length());
                            operatorBilling.setFileSize(str1[j]);
                        }

                        if(str1[j].contains("downloadTime:")){
                          str1[j] = str1[j].substring(13,str1[j].length());

                          operatorBilling.setDownloadSize(new  Timestamp(Long.valueOf(str1[j])));

                       }

                    }
                    operatorBillingList.add(operatorBilling);
                }

            }
            conn.disconnect();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return operatorBillingList;

       }

    }
```

**Hello.jsp file**

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>

<spring:url scope="page" var="jqueryUrl"
            value="/resources/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"/>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html>
<body>
<form:form id="operatorForm" modelAttribute="operatorBilling">
    <h4>test</h4>

    <div id="operatorID"></div>

    <c:url var="findOperatingURL" value="/hello"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.getJSON('${findOperatingURL}', {
                ajax: 'true'
            }, function (data) {
                alert("inside data!!!!");
                var html = '';
                var len = data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    html += '<div>' + data[i].uname + '</div><div>' + data[i].fileSize + '</div><div>'+data[i].fileName+'</div>';
                }
                $('#operatorID').html(html);
            });
        });
    </script>

    </div>
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**servlet.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"

             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing
        infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model <mvc:annotation-driven /> -->
    <annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources
        in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/"/>
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.springapp.mvc"/>
</beans:beans>
```

**web.xml file**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: This site isn't meant for code review. Please post if you have a problem.

Comment: I have highlighted my problem very first. i shared my code to show up what exactly i have done.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis   he stated his problem.. "hello.jsp is not getting invoked."

Comment: @JerylCook This question is an example of a question that does display any research effort. It doesn't include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, or the expected results. It just says: it doesn't work, fix it. It makes it really hard for us to help if we don't have all the details.

Comment: Initially i faced issue with accept header requests due to which even JSON didn't get retrieved. After resolving the same i faced this rendering issue after which i posted it here.

Comment: Issue resolved after changing the Jquery url to - <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">  </script> in hello.jsp file

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use RestTemplate within the Object getOperatorBillingDetails() method.

add the value attribute:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces="application/json;charset=utf-8" value = "/")
```

Comment: The header you propose won't help. OP's problem is a misunderstanding of program flow.

Comment: @Jeryl I tried adding value attribute. But still the same issue. I tried adding two handlers as per Sotirios comment. But JSON method inside Hello.jsp is not getting invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Before I give any details, drop your parsing solution and use a proper JSON parser/generator. Choose from

- [Gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
- [JSR 353: Java API for Json processing](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=353)
- [FasterXML/Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)
- [Simple JSON](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

And tons more. Don't reinvent the wheel. Note your solution would fail, if the new line characters appeared somewhere else.

---

For the real deal, for which request URL do you expect to see your `jsp`? Your handler method `getOperatorBillingDetails` is mapped to the URL path `/hello` and it returns a `List<OperatorBilling>`. There's no reference to a `jsp` or view name anywhere.

It seems you've mixed up some concepts.

`Servlet` and `jsp` are server side components while `javascript` is a client side component. In your scenario you need two handler methods. One to handle an HTTP request for the `hello.jsp` that will produce an HTTP response containing the HTML generated by that `jsp`. Then you need another handler method that will handle the AJAX request you have in the javascript script contained in the generated HTML.

Comment: As you said I have added two handler methods one for displaying the JSP page and the other for AJAX request. But still i don't get the alert inside the hello.jsp file inside the JSON method when running the same.

Comment: @samba If you aren't getting the alert, then the AJAX request didn't behave as you would expect. Try debugging it.

Comment: I believe people having questions post issues in this blog. I tried debugging it but couldn't fix. so posted here if anyone could find what's fault vth the code.

Answer (score 0):

have you put Jackson JSON in your class path use following cordinates for maven project

```
    <!-- Jackson JSON Mapper -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had this dependency already. Code is working fine.  It was issue with Hello.jsp file which was been resolved. I have attached the working code now.

Answer (score 0):

Still not working ??
don't return "OperatorBilling", just make its proxy object or VO object then try it.